# Extract table from Google BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to extract table from Google BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage using APIs. It does exports data to compressed(GZIP) CSV file to google storage. But it does not give the public access to that file. Is there any option to make exported file public through same API call?

I added another api call to make that file public but it gives me an error  `insufficientPermissions` even after adding required role to the service account.

Comment: You should instead make a dedicated bucket that is PUBLIC on the bucket level so all objects posted there gets public.

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform the 2 operations in the same call.

- 1 call for extracting data
- 1 call for changing the ACL, our put your file in a public bucket.

However, you extract data from your database and you let them publicly accessible in bucket? Are you sure?